# Cocos2d: AttributeError: 'Director' object has no attribute '_window_virtual_width'

Tags: python, cocos2d-iphone

We are using the cocos2d framework to create a game.  We're completely new to this framework, so we cannot get the director object to work as we are expecting.  Here is our code skeleton:

```
from cocos.director import director
from cocos.layer import base_layers


import sys
import math
import os

import pyglet
import cocos


world_width = 1000
world_height = 1000
class NetworkMap(cocos.layer.ScrollableLayer):
    def __init__(self, world_width, world_height):
        self.world_width = world_width
        self.world_height = world_height
        super(NetworkMap, self).__init__()
        bg = ColorLayer(170,170,0,255,width=500,height=500)
        self.px_width = world_width
        self.px_height = world_height
        self.add(bg,z=0)

class TestScene(cocos.scene.Scene):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestScene,self).__init__()

    def on_enter():
        director.push_handlers(self.on_cocos_resize)
        super(TestScene, self).on_enter()

    def on_cocos_resize(self, usable_width, usable_height):
        self.f_refresh_marks()

def main():
    scene = TestScene()
    director.init(world_width, world_height, do_not_scale=True)
    world_map = NetworkMap(world_width, world_height)
    scroller = cocos.layer.ScrollingManager()
    scroller.add(world_map)
    scene.add(scroller)
    director.run(scene)
```

So for some reason the director doesn't have all the attributes we want. 
Our stack trace is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "map.py", line 49, in <module>
main()
File "map.py", line 39, in main
scene = TestScene()
File "map.py", line 29, in __init__
super(TestScene,self).__init__()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cocos2d-0.5.5-py2.7.egg/cocos/scene.py",     line 95, in __init__
super(Scene,self).__init__()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cocos2d-0.5.5-py2.7.egg/cocos/cocosnode.py", line 114, in __init__
self.camera = Camera()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cocos2d-0.5.5-py2.7.egg/cocos/camera.py", line 56, in __init__
 self.restore()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cocos2d-0.5.5-py2.7.egg/cocos/camera.py", line 76, in restore
 width, height = director.get_window_size()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cocos2d-0.5.5-py2.7.egg/cocos/director.py", line 522, in get_window_size
 return ( self._window_virtual_width, self._window_virtual_height)
AttributeError: 'Director' object has no attribute '_window_virtual_width'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to initialise the director before you instantiate your first scene. The director is the global object that initialises your screen, sets up the Cocos2D framework, etc.

I found a few other errors:

- You need to change `ColorLayer` to be fully qualified, e.g. `cocos.layer.ColorLayer`.
- `on_enter` needs to have `self` as the first argument.
- You need to define `f_refresh_marks` in your TestScene class.

Here's a working copy of the code. (Working, in the sense that it does not throw errors, not that it does any sort of scrolling.)

```
from cocos.director import director
from cocos.layer import base_layers


import sys
import math
import os

import pyglet
import cocos


world_width = 1000
world_height = 1000
class NetworkMap(cocos.layer.ScrollableLayer):
    def __init__(self, world_width, world_height):
        self.world_width = world_width
        self.world_height = world_height
        super(NetworkMap, self).__init__()
        bg = cocos.layer.ColorLayer(170,170,0,255,width=500,height=500)
        self.px_width = world_width
        self.px_height = world_height
        self.add(bg,z=0)

class TestScene(cocos.scene.Scene):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestScene,self).__init__()

    def on_enter(self):
        director.push_handlers(self.on_cocos_resize)
        super(TestScene, self).on_enter()

    def on_cocos_resize(self, usable_width, usable_height):
        self.f_refresh_marks()

    def f_refresh_marks(self):
        pass

def main():
    director.init(world_width, world_height, do_not_scale=True)
    scene = TestScene()
    world_map = NetworkMap(world_width, world_height)
    scroller = cocos.layer.ScrollingManager()
    scroller.add(world_map)
    scene.add(scroller)
    director.run(scene)

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Comment: Interesting:  their "do this first" quickstart example code does try to init the director but still gives me the error.  http://python.cocos2d.org/doc/programming_guide/quickstart.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue (with a very similar stack trace) and it was because I was trying to create a layer before calling director.init(). Moving director.init() to earlier in the code fixed it for me.